# Getting the virtual comport addr from SOCAT command with grep

Tags: linux, sed, grep, regular-expression, pipe

I need the address of virtual com ports which are being generated by socat generally it is /dev/pts/2 and /dev/pts/3. I need these address as sometimes it changes from the original one. I need this as i am trying to create an application which need these addresses every time system restarts.

I tried various ways to get the same but no success 
as

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1| sed  "2,3d"
```

is giving output

> 2020/06/02 01:20:02 socat[24206] N PTY is /dev/pts/4

but

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1| sed '2,3d'|cut -d " " -f 7
```

> 

gives no output

i need to store  2 com port address in 2 variables and then pass them to my application 
Thanks for help and support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The false problem (and its solution)

Your problem as described in the question is due to block buffering instead of line buffering, which happens for some commands to optimize performance when the command's output isn't a terminal. Either the command has an option and you can use it. Here: [`sed -u`](https://manpages.debian.org/sed/sed.1) to get:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 2>&1| sed -u '2,3d' |cut -d " " -f 7
```

or it doesn't, and you can use generic tools like [`stdbuf`](https://manpages.debian.org/coreutils/stdbuf.1) or [`unbuffer`](https://manpages.debian.org/expect/unbuffer.1) to avoid this to happen. For example, if you add a new pipeline after `cut`, you'd probably have to use:

```
[...] | stdbuf -oL cut -d " " -f 7 | [...]
```

That said... just forget about it for your actual problem. Parsing debug output isn't the best method to achieve something. For example my version of `socat` outputs the ptys in lines 1 and 2, and I would need `sed -u 3d` etc.

---

### The actual solution

Actually, [`socat`](https://manpages.debian.org/socat/socat.1) has an option to deal with your specific problem:

> `PTY`
>
> Generates a pseudo terminal (pty) and uses its master side.
>
> [...]
>
> Useful options: **link**, openpty, wait-slave, mode, user, group

Later:

> **PTY option group**
>
> These options are intended for use with the pty address type.
>
> `link=<filename>`
>
> Generates a symbolic link that points to the actual pseudo terminal
>   (pty). **This might help to solve the problem that ptys are generated
>   with more or less unpredictable names**, making it difficult to directly
>   access the socat generated pty automatically. With this option, the
>   user can **specify a "fix" point in the file hierarchy that helps him to
>   access the actual pty (example)**. Beginning with socat version 1.4.3,
>   the symbolic link is removed when the address is closed (but see
>   option unlink-close).

In the [EXAMPLES](https://manpages.debian.org/socat/socat.1#EXAMPLES) section:

> ```
> socat PTY,link=$HOME/dev/vmodem0,rawer,wait-slave \
> EXEC:"ssh modemserver.us.org socat - /dev/ttyS0,nonblock,rawer"
> ```
>
> [...]

So you can solve the problem like this:

```
socat pty,raw,echo=0,link=$HOME/socatpty1 pty,raw,echo=0,link=$HOME/socatpty2
```

which creates for example:

```
$ ls -l $HOME/socatpty[12]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 11 Jun  1 21:58 /home/user/socatpty1 -> /dev/pts/15
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 11 Jun  1 21:58 /home/user/socatpty2 -> /dev/pts/16
```

You might have to cleanup those links later or before, especially if `socat` is interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, that was quite helpful